# Get as object using id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a method which take obj as parameter. I can't change the signature and I wan to reuse it. I have to send an element as object to this parameter so not sure how to do it. Can anyone show me?

```
function someUsefulFunction(obj) {
  var id = obj.id;
  //do other stuff
}

{
  ...
  var myElement = $('#myElement');
   someUsefulFunction(myElement); //getting error "TypeError: obj.id is undefined"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
```

looks like its expecting a dom node, so you can do this the old fashioned plain js way.

or if you want to do it with jquery,

```
var myElement = $('#myElement').get(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change to this:

```
var id = obj[0].id;
```

```js
function someUsefulFunction(obj) {
  var id = obj.id;
  console.log(id);
}

var myElement = $('#myElement').get(0);
someUsefulFunction(myElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

Alternative you can:

```
var myElement = $('#myElement').get(0);
```

```js
function someUsefulFunction(obj) {
  var id = obj[0].id;
  console.log(id);
}

var myElement = $('#myElement');
someUsefulFunction(myElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement"></div>
```